# How to add flags in command line GCC/G++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compilation, g++, compiler-flags

i started using Visual Studio Code and the compiler GCC/G++ (using mingw) to learn C++ and while searching for tutorials on how to configure the compiler, i noticed that every tutorial tells me to do like so : "Add the following flag to your command line: ". I don't really understand what/were is the command line.

do i absolutely have to use the Command Prompt to compile something ?

Comment: If you don't understand then you are not using it. Edit your `tasks.json` instead.

Comment: This is the tutorial you should follow: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: Pay careful attention to this part when you want to add more than 1 source file: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)